# C version of C++ std::map

Tags: c++, c

Is there a C library version of the C++ std::map in a standard library?

Comment: It doesn't have a map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` is not a hash table. Therefore, my suggestion: [Red-Black Tree C Code](http://www.mit.edu/~emin/source_code/red_black_tree/index.html)

> The following C files implement balanced binary trees using the red-black paradigm. I have written these functions in a very general manner so that the key can be anything at all. Each node of the balanced binary tree must contain a key and a pointer to info. The user defines what data-type the key is and provides a comparison function for the keys. The info can also be any kind of data type.

(Disclaimer: haven't tried it myself.)

Answer (score 4):

The C standard library does not support such an equivalent. However, a commonly used C library is [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/) from the GNOME project. In particular, the [GLib Hash Tables](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Did the question change, or did you just roll to disbelieve that anyone would actually want a tree rather than a hash? ;-) The GLib tree is here: http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into the standard library, but [uthash](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/) may meet your needs.